# Dereferencing std::vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, stdvector

I have a quick (and possibly stupid) question, but I couldn't find an answer online:

When I pass a struct by reference, I can nicely and cleanly access its fields via `MyArray->Field1`, `MyArray->Field2` etc.

Is there a similar way to do this for the elements of a `std::vector`? The only way to do this I know, is something like `MyVector[0][0]`, `MyVector[0][1]` etc. or maybe do something like `std::vector<double> MyVector2 = *MyVector;` and then `MyVector2[0, 1, 2...] = 1.0...`

**Edit:** Wow, was Stackoverflow quick closing my question...

I think, I got passing by reference and passing by pointer confused. I'm not sure, what the better solution in my case is: Basically I have a class where I set a `std::vector*` to an "external" `std::vector`. It uses this vector a lot of times, so I don't want to copy it all the time for performance reasons (and also the class changes it). Passing it by pointer, as mentioned above, I have to write something like `MyVector[0][0] = 3;` and while this works perfectly, it just doesn't look very nice.

The better way of writing this, according to wohlstads answer (thank you for the good explanation) would be `(*MyVector)[0] = 3;`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, it's not clear what exactly you are trying to do. Maybe you are interested in creating a [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) from a slice of your vector's data?

Comment: Maybe you're confusing terms, passing pointer parameters doesn't mean the same as passing by reference parameters.

Comment: Maybe just `(*MyVector)[0][0]`, etc. But, as already said, we need more clarity.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you, I got passing pointer parameters and reference parameters confused.

Comment: Regarding you last edit: I think using pass-by-reference is prefered even in this case. If you have a `std::vector* p`, you can still pass it by reference to a method accepting a `std::vector &` by using passing `*p`. Reference syntax is cleaner than pointer syntax, plus a reference cannot be null so you don't need to check this.

Comment: @wohlstad I tried that (for a minute), but the class then wanted an initializer for this (probably because a reference cannot be null?). I think, I'll go with a reference for cleaner code, but if I don't have an "external" `std::vector` yet I can set for the class, this seems a little bit messy...

Comment: You can keep the `std::vector<...>* p` pointing to the extrnal vector. You don't have to initialize any reference to null. You just need to pass `*p` to a method/function that accept a `std::vector<...> &`.

Comment: OK thanks. That seems like the cleanest way to go. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `std::vector` by refernce allows you to access its public members, e.g.:

```
void f(std::vector<int> & v)
{
    v.resize(1);
    v[0] = 3;
}
```

However, the syntax you used your question actually looks like passing by pointer. You can do that as well with a `std::vector` but in C++ we usually prefer to pass by reference. If you have a good reason to pass by pointer instead of a reference, you can do it like that:

```
void f(std::vector<int> * pV)
{
    pV->resize(1);
    (*pV)[0] = 3;
}
```

The brackets around `*pV` are necessary because operator `[]` has precedence over the dereferencing operator (`*`); without those, `*pV[0]` will be interpreted as `*(pV[0])`.